# how to add UTM Source to RSS Links?

Tags: feeds

I have pressflow 6.22 website (drupal 6.22). I need to add UTM Source to RSS links so i can track the page views that come from RSS in google analytics.
how can i do so?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using Google's [feedburner](https://feedburner.google.com) to consume your feeds, and then having the feedburner feeds versions listed on your site.

This way all the hard work is done for you.

There is a tutorial on this on [google's help page](https://www.google.com/support/feedburner/bin/answer.py?answer=165769)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an RSS feed of your own using the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views). It may seem a bit overkill to redefine the entire feed for just an extra parameter, but you may need more customization in the future, and having your feed served using Views allows all kinds of customizations in the future.

Comment: i am using views already!! but i don't find any option to customize the link!! where can i find such thing??
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

if you use RSS via Views Module you can customize the link by creating and editing the appropriate template (views-view-row-rss.tpl.php) link: 
https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-row-rss.tpl.php/7

If you try to rewrite the output of the link in Views, symbols as ?, &, # are converted in entities and wont help you to track links (actualy they will cause 404).